# Display a table query but group a category and display subcategory horizontally

Tags: php, mysql, categories

Here's my script so far..

```
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Category, Genre FROM skills";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
     // output data of each row
 while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
     echo "<br> Category: ". $row["Category"]. " - Genre: ". $row["Genre"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
     echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

.

I am trying to get a display to read like:

Category: Genre, Genre, Genre. Category: Genre, Genre, Genre.

I have 15 different Categories in mySQL table, with anything between 5-15 genres for each category.

I have done something similar a while ago in Microsoft Access with the help of primary keys, but I am lost without access (now on Mac having to learn php & sql)

Comment: Could you please explain better what you want to display?

Comment: ahh crud... I can't even display what I need too :(   -dang this thang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `GROUP_CONCAT()` function to concatenate all genres for each category, and then simply loop through the result set.

Here are the relevant references:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

So you need to change your SQL query from

```
$sql = "SELECT Category, Genre FROM skills";
```

to

```
$sql = "SELECT Category, GROUP_CONCAT(Genre SEPARATOR ', ') as Genre FROM skills GROUP BY Category";
```

Here's the complete code:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
     die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT Category, GROUP_CONCAT(Genre SEPARATOR ', ') as Genre FROM skills GROUP BY Category";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0){
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "Category: ". $row["Category"]. " - Genre: ". $row["Genre"]. "<br />";
    }
}else {
    echo "0 results";
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: but can I repeat this?! actually.. I just take away the line breaks and it will ;)

Comment: @DamoDiggler ya, you can do that. If you remove the `<br />` tag then it'll  echo everything in one line.

Comment: Yes, that's great... exactly what I wanted to achieve! a thousand "thank you"s :)